# How to evaluate string that have exponential

Tags: java, eval

Javax ScriptEngine and JEval works similarly, you input an string and send it to be evaluated, and it will return you the result of it:

In ScriptEngine (almost the same in JEval):

```
System.out.println(engine.eval("2*3+4"));
```

will result in:

```
10.0
```

But when I try to make it an exponential:

```
System.out.println(engine.eval("2^3+4"));
```

will result in:

```
5.0
```

But it really should result in 12 (2^3 = 8, 8+4=12), so my question is how can I set it up in a way that the string which the will be all the whole equation, will evaluate supporting the exponential, and result correctly?

Should I use another library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is the XOR operand, your string means `2 XOR 3 + 4`, which in facts evaluates to `1 + 4`.

You have to use

```
Math.pow(2,3) + 4
```

This is my code:

```
System.out.println(engine.eval("Math.pow(2,3) + 4"));
```

Output:

```
12.0
```

Comment: No other way to bypass Math.pow?

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa I'm afraid the only way would be to hardcode the power like `engine.eval("2 * 2 * 2 + 4")`, but what if you will have to evaluate `2^10000`? I think `Math.pow` would be the only way

Comment: Thanks BackSlash, since this is the only way, I'm opening another question that relates to this, please give it a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836669/regex-to-capture-float-from-string-and-replace-with-the-captured-float