# Regex to capture float from string (and replace with the captured float)

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have the following expressions:

```
2^3+4
5*3 + log(9) + 32/4 - 2.1^5
44 - 22 + sin(30)*2.34 + 51.32^4 + 17*32/11
```

I want to find and capture the before '^' number and the after, then replace it with Math.pow(captured1,captured2);
so the strings will be like:

```
Math.pow(2,3)+4
5*3 + log(9) + 32/4 - Math.pow(2.1,5)
44 - 22 + sin(30)*2.34 + Math.pow(51.32,4) + 17*32/11
```

It have to be compatible with Java regex.

My thoughts about it:

Find:

```
(.*\d(\.\d)?)\^(.*\d(\.\d)?)
```

Replace:

```
Math.pow(\1,\2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String result = subject.replaceAll("(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\^(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "Math.pow($1,$2)");
```

Comment: What about negative numbers and compound expressions in parentheses? Do we not care about them?

Comment: You're right about negative numbers, of course. The question was only about numbers, not about compound expressions - in a case like this, regexes aren't the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong technology for this job. You need a scanner and an expression parser. What if they aren't numbers? What if they are subexpressions, e.g. `log(9)^sin(2)?` What if they're in parentheses? Multiple parentheses?